# UIScrollView Not Scrolling Properly

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

This is what i have so far, I have a scroller and two buttons that i want to be on the scroller, but i cant get to the second button because it wont scroll around to it. I would greatly appreciate if anyone can see the error in my code.

```
    UIScrollView *mainScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 65, 320, 4000)];
mainScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 4000);
mainScroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
[self.view addSubview:mainScroll];
[mainScroll setScrollEnabled:YES];


UIButton *mainCreateGame = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[mainCreateGame addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(goToCreateGameViewController)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[mainScroll addSubview:mainCreateGame];
mainCreateGame.frame = CGRectMake(75, 10, 170, 60);



UIButton *anotherButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[anotherButton addTarget:self
                  action:@selector(goFuckOffApple)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[mainScroll addSubview: anotherButton];
anotherButton.frame = CGRectMake(75, 3000, 170, 60);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, besides the hilarious method names (goF**kOffApple, LOL), you are setting your scroll view's frame to the same size as it's content.  Frame and content size are different animals.  Try this:

```
 UIScrollView *mainScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 65, 320, 395)];
mainScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 4000);
mainScroll.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
[self.view addSubview:mainScroll];
[mainScroll setScrollEnabled:YES];


UIButton *mainCreateGame = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[mainCreateGame addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(goToCreateGameViewController)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[mainScroll addSubview:mainCreateGame];
mainCreateGame.frame = CGRectMake(75, 10, 170, 60);



UIButton *anotherButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[anotherButton addTarget:self
                  action:@selector(goFuckOffApple)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[mainScroll addSubview: anotherButton];
anotherButton.frame = CGRectMake(75, 3000, 170, 60);
```

Comment: lol... i was kinda mad at apple by that point. hahahaha thanks a ton man. =)